# SQL - Copy column in another table // Find family relation in a tree

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently trying to build a **repository table** (or find an alternative solution) to allow me to identify easily "family" relations between some elements.

It is basically a **tree structure** with several elements linked to each others in an oracle sql database.

Each element has at least one parent and all of them are identified by a code. The parent code of one element is easily accesible in a table.

I have been trying to copy the the "code" column into an empty repository table, using the following code :

```
UPDATE TARGET_TABLE 
SET TARGET_TABLE.CODE1 =
(SELECT CODE1 FROM SOURCE_TABLE)


INSERT INTO TARGET_TABLE (CODE1)
SELECT CODE1 FROM SOURCE_TABLE;
```

I dont have any error when I am executing these request, but nothing happen in the target table.. "0 row updated"

I have been trying to do it without creating a new table, and I am able to find the code with the following commands :

```
SELECT DAD_CODE1 FROM SOURCE_TABLE where 'CODE=1000' IN CODE; -- give 0900 as result, being the dad of 1000
SELECT DAD_CODE1 FROM SOURCE_TABLE where 'CODE=0900' IN CODE; -- give null if root
```

etc.. until NULL result when I reach the root.

or the other way around :

```
SELECT CODE FROM SOURCE_TABLE WHERE '00001' IN DAD_CODE1 -- give 0100, among other children codes of this dad element 
SELECT CODE FROM SOURCE_TABLE WHERE '00100' IN DAD_CODE1 -- give null if no children
```

and this is working, but I am unable to build it "recursively".
The purpose would be to find relations easily for other data processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UPDATE` statement will only update rows which already exist, so if TARGET_TABLE is empty then you should get "0 rows updated" as there's nothing to update.

The `INSERT` statement will insert as many rows into TARGET_TABLE as there are in SOURCE_TABLE.

[You can see this for yourself by looking at this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=91b2bde6be9090220abf7b5c3aaf5eed)

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I am using the INSERT, none of the rows into SOURCE_TABLE get copied into TARGET_TABLE. I have actually an error message : "cannot insert NULL in ("DB"."TARGET_TABLE"."ID")

Comment: That's because there's a column named `ID` in TARGET_TABLE which has to be given a value. Typically the population of this field would be done using a trigger which would obtain the value from a sequence, but apparently this hasn't been done in the case of the database/table you're working with. As I don't have access to your database I really can't offer any specific advice on how to set the `ID` field correctly. If this is a work or school problem you might try asking a colleague, another student, or your teacher/professor. Best of luck.

Comment: One way to do it (working in my db) is to directly add the column when creating a new table :
CREATE TABLE TARGET_TABLE
AS (SELECT CODE1, DAD_CODE FROM SOURCE_TABLE);